# Do Windows Vista programs work on Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, windows-vista

I purchased some old software that was made for Windows Vista. Will they work on Ubuntu? Will they work on Windows 7 or 8?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please save questions which are not about Ubuntu for forums specific to those products. I appreciate that you are also asking about Ubuntu, but it would be good to stick to Ubuntu and not go onto asking about compatibility of software with other Operating Systems.

Answer (score 1):

Yes but you need WINE https://www.winehq.org/ I recommend latest Development version 1.7.34 (since you said programs are old there is high change they will work great with WINE) for Ubuntu and for Windows if they don't run at first try enabling compability mode but I haven't yet needed to do that so I think you wouldn't too.